# Flask SQLAlchemy query filter with ".all()" does NOT return all rows

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to return all rows for a particular user_id. 
When I run the query #1 and #2 below it only returns the first row that it finds, even though I'm specifying `.all()`.

When I use `.with_entities` as in case #3, all rows are returned as expected.

I would appreciate a second pair of eyes. Thank you.

I'm using MySQLDB (5.5.47 version), Flask 0.10.1 and SQL-Alchemy 2.1 if that matters.

1. Returns first row only:

   ```
   result = MyUserClass.query.filter_by(user_id=self.user_id).all()
   ```
2. This also returns first row only:

   ```
   result = MyUserClass.query.filter(MyUserClass.user_id == self.user_id).all()
   ```
3. Works and returns all rows as expected:

   ```
   MyUserClass.query.filter_by(user_id=self.user_id).with_entities(MyUserClass.myColumn).all()
   ```

Comment: Is `user_id` marked as a primary column?

Comment: Hi, No user_id is not the primary key. Does it have to be?

Comment: I'm trying to find reasons for the behaviour. If it was marked as a primary key or has a uniqueness constraint on it, that could point to issues.

Comment: Could you add the full definition of `MyUserClass`?

Comment: Aha! I found the problem. Martijn, you were right! The user_id was set as a primary key in the class definition but not in the MySQLDB table definition.

Comment: Removing the primary key entry from class definition fixed the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

used_id column was marked as the primary key column in the class definition (but not in the MySQLDB), as Martijn Pieters pointed out. Adding a new column and making it the primary key fixed the problem.

Comment: You should makr your solution as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the insights. In my case, I have been using views/mviews from redshift and they don't naturally have primary keys so i had to declare some primary keys where i thought would be unique combination of records.

And also one extra thing i needed to was adding this line to my schema

```
many=True
```

For example;

```
users_schema = UsersSchema(many=True)
```